# Mожно ли с одного аккаунта разработчика выкладывать несколько приложений?

Tags: android, google-play

Скажите пожалуйста можно ли с одного аккаунта разработчика выкладывать несколько приложений (если да то сколько ?) или на каждое приложение нужно регистрировать отдельно аккаунт и каждый раз платить 25$ ? заранее благодарю за ответ

Comment: с одного аккаунта можно выкладывать в маркет столько приложений, сколько вам нужно, каждый раз регистрировать новый аккаунт нет необходимости

Answer (score 3):

[По сбору](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6112435?hl=ru)

> Регистрационный сбор составляет 25 долларов США и взимается только
>   один раз. Его можно оплатить банковской картой следующих типов:
>
> MasterCard; Visa; American Express; Discover (только в США); Visa
>   Electron (за пределами США).
>
> Примечание. В некоторых странах могут поддерживаться не все типы карт.

По количеству приложений ограничений нет.

Все Продукты, распространяемые через Google Play, должны соответствовать [Правилам программы для разработчиков](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/#!?modal_active=none).

Answer (score 3):

Платишь один раз 25$, ограничений по количеству приложений нет. Если заблокируют 3 приложения за нарушения правил публикации, аккаунт забанят полностью.